# Using SHParseDisplayName with font files fails with 'The system cannot find the file specified.'

Tags: windows, api

I use the API SHParseDisplayName to get the PIDL of the font file "C:\Windows\fonts\arial.ttf" but the API fails with the error code -2147024894 'The system cannot find the file specified'.
The font file exists and is accessible using FindFirstFile.
I also tried it with other font files in the folder "C:\Windows\fonts" but i always get the same error.
Running the app with explicit admin rights didnt change anything too.
Im using Win7x64.

Does anyone know why the API SHParseDisplayName can't retrieve the PIDLs of files in the system font folder?